# Ubuntu 18.04 Invisible Mouse Cursor

Tags: mouse, mouse-pointer

A fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a old desktop of AMD6000 and Nvidia 8800gts worked very well when it was connected to a monitor, but as soon as I reboot it with a connection to the TV, the cursor disappears but the mouse and keyboard continues to work properly.

Which means I can continue working away based on the mouser-over events, but I've tried all the commands online from the past recommendations without any luck.

Does any one have any ideas?